# Prove $f$ is measure if $\exists S\in\Sigma: f(S)<\infty$

Tags: measure-theory

How do I prove that if for a function $f:\Sigma\to[0,\infty]$ defined on a $\sigma$-algebra

1. $\exists S\in\Sigma: f(S)<\infty,$
2. $S_1,S_2,\ldots\in\Sigma, S_i\cap S_j=\emptyset\;\forall i\ne j\Rightarrow f(\cup_{i=1}^\infty S_i)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(S_i)$,

then $f$ is a measure.

I see that I only have to show that $f(\emptyset)=0$ as the second condition is identical to the one in the original definition of measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\emptyset \cap \emptyset=\emptyset$ and $\emptyset \cup \emptyset=\emptyset$ so if $f(\emptyset)=x\neq 0$ then $x=f(\emptyset) =f(\emptyset \cup \emptyset)=f(\emptyset)+f(\emptyset)=2x,$  which is a contradiction.

Comment: What if $x=\infty$?

Comment: This can't happen, by condition 1. in the question

Comment: I agree,  but you didn’t write why $x$ couldn’t be $\infty$ in your answer.